# Why would a certain element not always print?

Tags: asp.net, css, printing

For the life of me I can't figure this one out.  I have a page that the user needs to print.  I have the print styles set up perfectly except for one bug...  There is a table that sometimes doesn't print.  Has anyone seen this before??

Could it be possible that the page was printed before the stylesheets are loaded?

Any ideas are welcome I'm stumped...

Comment: Fascinating.. you have a link or some source?

Comment: Sorry I can't share any source or even examples for this project.  I wish I could cause this is driving me nuts!!!  :)  I haven't even been able to reproduce it myself although I have a printout with everything but the table from a coworker so I know its not just a certain config on the users pc.

Comment: Are your printing problems confined to a certain browser?  Or, alternately, do they only occur on one particular system?

Comment: Have you changed your print stylesheet recently at all? It could, perhaps, have been a cached copy of an early/intermediate stylesheet causing that 1% of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an intermittent printing bug then there probably isn't much logic to it, not any we can discern without examples anyway.

My initial approach would be to shrink the table and ensure it's got plenty of margin around it,  so that it's not possible it could just be getting bumped off the page when the printer drivers render it.

Other than that, if it prints 99% of the time and this is just an intermittent bug, it's hard to say how to fix it.

If you have the time just start with a blank page and the table, so that it prints 100% of the time, and add back in other parts of the page until it stops working.  But sounds like a lot of work!

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  I was just hoping someone has had a similar issue in their experience.  I'll definitely try shrinking down the table a bit in hopes it helps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your print stylesheet is disabling your table, i.e.

```
table {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but that not the issue.  99% of the time it prints fine.  It's just that 1% the table doesn't print...

Comment: are you saying that with exactly the same html it prints fine 99% of the time? if so this sounds like a browser/printer driver bug.

Comment: I would agree that it may have to do with the browser.  I still can't have it consitantly reproduced.  Starting to think this may have been a bad question...